# сообщения программы выводятся в одно уведомление

Tags: linux, c

Использую gio в glib, которое выводит сообщения в области уведомлений. Я когда только тестировал программу, для добавления в основную, то сообщения были раздельными. То есть если написать успеть 10 сообщений, то появиться 10 уведомлений. К сожеланию этот код я перезаписал на другой ( когда тестировал другую функциональность ). И теперь все сообщения выводятся в одно уведомление и получается что если кто-то напишет мне в чате сообщение, а потом напишет в этот же момент другой в чате, то уведомление обновиться.
Я использую только стандартные возможности, это создать nitificator.

```
notify = g_notification_new ( "twitch" );
g_notification_set_priority ( notify, G_NOTIFICATION_PRIORITY_HIGH
```

и отсылаю уведомления, я остановился на GNotifications именно из-за того, что уведомления были раздельными, если написать от одной программы.

```
                g_notification_set_body ( notify, body );
                g_application_send_notification ( app, prog, notify );
```

Я использую xubuntu, и в ней всё работало. Но потом я  может что-то изменил.

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался почему, ну почти разобрался. Вся проблема в том, я делал в отдельном потоке ( но ни это проблема ), а проблема в `g_main_loop`, если использовать эту петлю, то сообщения будут выводиться в одно уведомление. Если же использовать `pthread_join` чтобы ожидать поток, то уведомления будут отдельными.